# GnuPG Deccryption using Java Runtime Process Bad Session Key Error

Tags: java, gnupg

I have a Encrypted file from a source and I have recieved the Private Key and Passphrase in files to devrypt the files. As suggested in SO post I am trying to decrypt the files using the Runtime Process but face the following error

```
DECRYPT COMMAND: [gpg, --no-tty, --output, output.xml, --batch, --homedir, C:/Users/sivasaravanan.v/AppData/Roaming/gnupg, --passphrase, src/main/resources/gpg/my_pwd, --decrypt, src/main/resources/gpg/abc.xml.gpg]
DECRYPT exitCode: 2
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
Exception in thread "main" com.xxx.xxxx.xxx.decrypt.ProcessException: Unexpected exit code: 2
```

I have tried importing keys but still face the same issue everytime. However If I use the console it works and I am able to decrypt the file. However here the code always exits with code 2 (Unexpected Error)

The Main Code is as follows

```
String[] command = new String[] {
    "gpg",
    "--no-tty",
    "--output",
    "output.xml",
    "--batch",
    "--homedir",
    "C:/Users/sivasaravanan.v/AppData/Roaming/gnupg",
    "--passphrase",
    "src/main/resources/gpg/my_pwd",
    "--decrypt",
    "src/main/resources/gpg/abc.xml.gpg"
};


try {
    Process gpgProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    try {
          {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gpgProcess.getInputStream()));
            try {
              String line;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                processOutput.append(line).append("\n");
              }
            }
            finally {
              reader.close();
            }
          }
          {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gpgProcess.getErrorStream()));
            try {
              String line;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.err.println(line);
              }
            }
            finally {
              reader.close();
            }
          }
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
          throw new ProcessException("Data unavailable", e);
        }
        final int exitCode;
        try {
          exitCode = gpgProcess.waitFor();
          System.out.println("DECRYPT exitCode: " + exitCode);
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e) {
          throw new ProcessException("Interrupted before process", e);
        }
        if (0 != exitCode) {
          throw new ProcessException("Unexpected exit code: " + exitCode, exitCode);
        }
        System.out.println(processOutput);
        return processOutput.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to execute GPG decrypt command via command line: " + e.getMessage());
    } 

    return processOutput.toString();
```

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

I have tried the BouncyCastle library also but the EncryptedData has PGPPBEEncryptedData and not  PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData as suggested in different posts and hence that is also facing error.

Comment: Does GPG read a passphrase from a file like that? I'd also guess you want `gpgProcess.getOutputStream()` not InputStream. But this should be possible to do with with BouncyCastle: you say that is facing error because it doesn't match the code samples you've already found? Can't you adapt the samples for symmetric encryption?

Comment: Yes . I am reading the passphrase from a file as its encrypted also. Regarding Bouncy Castle I have adapted the Symetric Decryption example but data check validation fails. `PGPPBEEncryptedData var6 = (PGPPBEEncryptedData) var4.get(0);
  InputStream var7 = var6.getDataStream((new JcePBEDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder(
    (new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()).setProvider("BC").build())).setProvider("BC")
      .build(var1));`